# Closeness of coordinates in two groups with memory constraints

Tags: python

I have two groups of coordinates:

1. `{(x1,y1),..(xn,yn)}`
2. `{(u1,v1),..(un,vn)}`

and I am using a KDTree implementation to match each pair in group 2 to the pair in group 1 to which it is closest.

Considering that both my groups are too big to store on a computer, then in order to perform this task I am thinking about doing the following:

1. I can store all the coordinates for group 1 and then for each element of group 2 query for the nearest element.
2. Or, I can store a say 50% of all the coordinates for group 1 and then for each element of group 2 query for the nearest element and save their distances. Then, I can save the other 50% of coordinates in group 1 and then for each element of group 2 query for the nearest element and save their distances. Now, I can compare the both the distances with each other to determine which is the lesser value and the smaller of the two distances will enable me to identify the nearest element.

Is there a more efficient method of finding the closest element in 2 groups given that there are memory constraints?

Comment: Does this need to be exact, or are approximations allowed? Also, how are these points distributed?

Comment: @arshajii Hi -- can you comment on both instances if possible and any guarantees on how much I may be loosing with the approximate method? thanks.